# Termination on direct script access

Tags: php, security, web

I got over this kind of security measure in a bunch of php projects. On top of every php file, there is a check if the script is invoked through direct access (e.g. via browser) or if it was properly included/required by the sites entry point:

```
if(!defined('SYSTEM_ENTRYPOINT'))
    die();
```

Is this a good practice to use in php projects? What should I consider when doing so? Are there edge cases? What data could possibly be exposed when not checking this?

Comment: I believe you won't be needing that if all your php files are outside the webroot and you only expose the entry point in the webroot.

Comment: @frz3993 In my current case, everything is in one place.

Comment: Ok. Then, it depends what you have in your files. Let's say if a file contain only variables or only classes. Invoking it directly will only produce a blank page. If you have some instructions in the file, they will certainly be executed.

Comment: It depends, but 99% of the files just contain classes. Would you say that checking this only make sense in files with "direct code"? Im afraid the information within the php error messages could help possible attackers to snoop around or gain additional information about the structure of the project.

Comment: I think so, it only make sense with "direct code". Yes, error messages can tell a lot about the structure, for example if your entry point failed to include a file, the error message will show the path to the file, even if you have that check. No error will be displayed if you navigate to a  class file directly, because it doesn't process anything. On production, usually I will redirect to an error page and log or mail the error. Never letting the error shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle that with URL rewrites. Organize your php files in a way so the visitor cannot touch your program logic.

For example, separate your code into two dirs: web and src. Web ahould contian only index.php ant htaccess file to route all requests to it. Src should all the program logic (controllers, db access abd so on). Inside src/index.php, code some logic that will decide which controller from src folder to include.

Make "web" directory your site's web root, and visitors won't be able to access any other php file.

Comment: That would be a solution and I also thought about this earlier. I used constants for definig several important locations of my source, so that would be no big thing. I'm gonna accept this as answer for now, but maybe there is still something to contribute about the original idea.

Comment: If possible, configure your vhost (Apache, nginx) to point to a `public/` directory and keep all of your application code and ESPECIALLY configuration files outside of this directory. i.e. `/var/www/public` and `/var/www/src`.